# How do I change the font size in elsarticle class?

Tags: fontsize, elsarticle

First I used `elsart` and as usual the text font was 12pt, title font was 17pt **bold**, author font was 14.5pt and the address font was 11pt. but in `elsarticle` class, text font is 10pt, title is 14.5pt and not bold, author's 10pt and address font is 8pt. Which one is standard and how can I change them all like a set?

Comment: Try `\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}`.

Comment: I used it, but the title is 17pt but is not bold, and the author font is 12 instead of 14.5, and address font is 10 instead of 11!

Answer (score 7):

> Which one is standard?

The migration to a newer document class should be considered the "current" standard (since [17 December 2009](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/authorsview.authors/elsarticle#package)). So, using [`elsarticle`](http://ctan.org/pkg/elsarticle) should be what you go with if you're producing a publication for Elsevier.

> How can I change them all like a set?

You should modify this at the document-level, rather than on an individual basis. The reason for this is that the other font sizes of document elements are relative to the base, most likely set using font switches like `\small`, `\large`, etc. Using

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
```

creates a `10pt` default text font size (since it's based on the classic [`article`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/article.cls) document class). You can also try class options `11pt` or `12pt`, which is supported by default.

---

Here are some more details regarding `elsarticle`:

The title (or `\maketitle` under the `final` or default option) is set using `\MaketitleBox`:

```
\long\def\MaketitleBox{%
  \resetTitleCounters
  \def\baselinestretch{1}%
  \begin{center}%
    \def\baselinestretch{1}%
    \Large\@title\par\vskip18pt
    \normalsize\elsauthors\par\vskip10pt
    \footnotesize\itshape\elsaddress\par\vskip36pt
    \hrule\vskip12pt
    \ifvoid\absbox\else\unvbox\absbox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    \ifvoid\keybox\else\unvbox\keybox\par\vskip10pt\fi
    \hrule\vskip12pt
  \end{center}%
}
```

setting the title in `\Large` (not bold), the author in `\normalsize` and the address in `\footnotesize`. If you want a **bold** title (`\bfseries`), `14.5pt` authors (`\large` or `14.4pt` under `12pt`) and `11pt` address (`\small` or `10.95pt` under `12pt`), you need to use

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}% `\normalsize is 12pt
\title{{\bfseries My title}}% Bold title, 17.28pt
\author{\large An Author}% \large or 14.4pt author
\address{\small Random City}% \small or 10.95pt address
\begin{document}
\maketitle
%...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As I said, I used the 12pt in class option. but yet I have the problems that I mentioned above: the title is 17pt but is not bold, and the author font is 12 instead of 14.5, and address font is 10 instead of 11!

Comment: @Mohammad: See my updated answer for modifications to meet your request.

Answer (score 5):

I published only one paper with Elsevier, but my experience was that the final version of the article looked completely different from the output that I got when compiling the document myself with `elsarticle`. So I would suggest you not to worry about the look of the paper in the preliminary versions. As long as the referees can read it, it's fine.

And in any case, if you really need to control font sizes and finer typography aspects in your paper, probably you have chosen the wrong document class to start with.

Comment: I completely agree with that. The only important thing that would change significantly with a change from 10pt to 12pt or vice versa would be the number of pages of the (submitted) article, and this can sometimes be important. Of course I do remember that for one of my papers I tried hard to squeeze the content on 8 pages and the printed article came up to 8.2 pages :-)